# How to generate a random vector with a triangular autocorrelation

Tags: probability, statistics

I am trying to generate N random vectors that when correlated with themselves converge to a triangular function.

The approaches I have been trying to follow are reversing a PCA procedure (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34724/reversing-pca-back-to-original-variables) and generating a triangular function out of uniform functions (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution#Generating_Triangular-distributed_random_variates), but I am stuck. Any hint will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did it following this link:

http://www.sitmo.com/article/generating-correlated-random-numbers/